# UPDATE status on last record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these fields: 
ID,
ContractID,
ClientID,
Date,
DueDate,
Status

Each client can only have 1 active contract at a time, I want to update the last record of the table to set itself to "inactive" when a new record is added, the new record must set itself to "active".

I had a stored procedure that did something like this, but i'm not sure if it'll work.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE ClientID='f0004' AND contractID='1')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Contracts(Status) VALUES ('Active')
END
```

Comment: I think you need a trigger for this.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a trigger to inactivate all rows for a customer prior to creating the new one.

You can also update all to inactive first, then insert the new one as active, both operations within a single transaction.